# Using Nodejs and oauth with gmail

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, gmail

I understand the concept of oauth for the most part. I've done quite a bit of research, but I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding how to use oauth to gain access to Gmail. I can't seem to find any concrete documentation for it.

I know there are a lot of node libraries for oauth, which one would you recommend me use? Is there any noob friendly tutorials for using node and oauth?

Just anything in general; I just need somewhere to start so I can understand how to apply oauth with nodejs.

I've used nodejs before, but I can't say I'm an expert in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get an access token by following the [Web Server Applications flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer). You can check out [node-oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) to accomplish this.

Then you need an IMAP library that supports Google's [XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol#the_sasl_xoauth2_mechanism). Fortunately there's [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap), that recently added this.